# jQuery - click-event is called twice on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with my web application which is designed for iPad.
I use jQuery and jQuery UI for dragging elements on the screen. Because on iPad, the element can not be dragged by default, I added this library:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/

Including it, I can drag and drop elements on iPad, but also a problem occurs. I have on the draggable element also a div are with an image, which should be clickable.

So I integrate these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".note").draggable();
    $('.closebutton').click(function() {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

​
The problem is, including the drag-library, the alert message `test` pops up twice or the screen is frozen.

I created a full working demo here:

http://jsbin.com/oliwo/2/

On normal desktop browsers, like Firefox 4 Beta and Safari, it works, only one `test` message appears by clicking with the mouse on the x - delete image. On iPad, I get the message twice or the screen froze.

Does anyone can help me? Thank you a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, but if I do not use `alert` messages, it will work. I create new elements and then it is only called once, on iPad and Desktop Safari.

Answer (score 5):

This is not really a response, as i don't known why you have it twice. But you can try a **workaround** if you're sure your click event is the only click event behavior that should be attached to this button; Make an unbind() just before you're bind, this will remove any previous click binding (so if this is run several times, you'll get only one event):

```
$('.closebutton').unbind().click(function() { ...
```

or better:

```
$('.closebutton').unbind('click').click(function() { ...
```

Comment: Does not work, I also got two alert messages... I think it is because the drag-library also handle the click/tap event and calls the click function twice.

Answer (score 4):

I've found that events get fired twice when showing an alert box on a click.  I've managed to overcome this problem by using a setTimeout to show the alert box...

```
$("#myButton").unbind("click").click(function () {
   // Have to use a setTimeout else on iPhone the alert may appear twice in certain scenarios
   setTimeout(function () {  alert('The message'); }, 300);
   return false;  // Return false to prevent href being followed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this issue only on iPad, perhaps some version of webkit related.  The unbind worked for me, and I also read this only exists if jquery code is in the body html tag, if its in head it is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

just simply avoid the propagation of the click

```
$("tr").live('click',function() {

        ...

        $( event.toElement ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
    });
```